# Canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg) to Image DataType in MS SQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, canvas

I am capturing a signature using a  element and processing the  element toDataURL. Afterward, I am posting this through ajax to a sqlsrv driver for MS SQL where I am inserting it into an "Image" Datatype column. The issue is I am running this is parallel to another program where the capturing system is capturing the signatures starting with 0xFFD8FF (etc) and the only way I can view them is to encode them to base64 while the DataURL is in another format and isn't working once I encode them to base64.

The code paraphrased is...

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url:"cgi-bin/php/post/ticket_signature.php",
            data: {
              ID        : '<?php echo $_GET['ID'];?>',
              Signature : $("#signature")[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '')
            },
            method:"POST",
            success:function(code){alert(code);}});
```

Sql:

```
sqlsrv_query($database, "INSERT INTO nei.dbo.PDATicketSignature(PDATicketID, Signature, SignatureType) VALUES(?,?,'C');",array($_POST['ID'],$_POST['Signature']));
```

HTML / PHP

```
<div class='col-xs-12'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php
        $r = sqlsrv_query($database,'SELECT * FROM PDATicketSignature WHERE PDATicketSignature.PDATicketID = ?',array($_GET['ID']));
        if($r){$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($r);
          if(is_array($row)){
            echo base64_encode($row['Signature']);
        }}?>' /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found from php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

> If you want to save data that is derived from a Javascript
>   canvas.toDataURL() function, you have to convert blanks into plusses.
>   If you do not do that, the decoded data is corrupted:

```
<?php
  $encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedData);
  $decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
?>
```

The real fix though happened to be using the array based parameter and setting the proper direction, datatype from php and datatype from ms sql.

```
sqlsrv_query($database, "SET TEXTSIZE 10000000;UPDATE nei.dbo.PDATicketSignature SET PDATicketSignature.Signature = ? WHERE PDATicketSignature.PDATicketID = ?;",array(array($data, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN,
    SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY),SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARBINARY('max')),$_POST['ID']));
```